# How to create Instagram ad for boosting a post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I have been working on Meta APIs for Ads creation for boosting instagram post

```
 curl \
 -F 'access_token=<TOKEN>' \
 -F 'object_story_id=<POST_ID>' \
 -F 'name=<NAME>' \
https://graph.facebook.com/<VERSION>/<ACCOUNT_ID>/adcreatives
```

After getting <CREATIVE_ID> from above cURL,

```
 curl \
  -F 'name=My Ad' \
  -F 'adset_id=<AD_SET_ID>' \
  -F 'creative={"creative_id":"<CREATIVE_ID>"}' \
  -F 'redownload=1' \
  -F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/ads
```

But above cURL always returns this response

```
 {
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "AZOAMrXAk1dKccDJlrZ7Mqp"
    }
}
```

I cannot understand why this error happens.
What could be the reason?

Thank You.